# Visual Studio 2013 Angular2 rc.1 with Typescript receiving compile errors for Angular typescript

Tags: visual-studio-2013, typescript, angular

I am trying to complete the Angular2 Quick Start using VS2013. I have installed Typescript 1.8.5 (which is the latest available for VS2013). I have followed numerous online guides and pieced them together for VS2013. When I run the build I get hundreds of errors in the Angular2 typings files similar to:

> Error 2   Build: '=' expected.    ..\ng_for.d.ts  7   14  Angular2Quickstart

Here's my systemjs.config.js:

```js
/**
 * System configuration for Angular 2 samples
 * Adjust as necessary for your application needs.
 */
(function (global) {
    // map tells the System loader where to look for things
    var map = {
        'app': 'app', // 'dist',
        '@angular': 'Scripts/lib/@angular',
        'rxjs': 'Scripts/lib/rxjs'
    };
    // packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
    var packages = {
        'app': { main: 'main.js', defaultExtension: 'js' },
        'rxjs': { defaultExtension: 'js' },
        'angular2-in-memory-web-api': { defaultExtension: 'js' },
    };
    var ngPackageNames = [
      'common',
      'compiler',
      'core',
      'http',
      'platform-browser',
      'platform-browser-dynamic',
      'router',
      'router-deprecated',
      'upgrade',
    ];
    // Add package entries for angular packages
    ngPackageNames.forEach(function (pkgName) {
        packages['@angular/' + pkgName] = { main: pkgName + '.umd.js', defaultExtension: 'js' };
    });
    var config = {
        map: map,
        packages: packages
    }
    System.config(config);
})(this);
```

And here's my package.json:

```js
{
    "name": "angular2demo",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "license": "ISC",
    "scripts": {
    "postinstall": "typings install",    
    "typings": "typings"
  },
    "dependencies": {
        "@angular/common":  "2.0.0-rc.1",
        "@angular/compiler":  "2.0.0-rc.1",
        "@angular/core":  "2.0.0-rc.1",
        "@angular/http":  "2.0.0-rc.1",
        "@angular/platform-browser":  "2.0.0-rc.1",
        "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic":  "2.0.0-rc.1",
        "@angular/router":  "2.0.0-rc.1",
        "@angular/router-deprecated":  "2.0.0-rc.1",
        "@angular/upgrade":  "2.0.0-rc.1",
        "systemjs": "0.19.27",
        "core-js": "^2.4.0",
        "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.3",
        "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.6",
        "zone.js": "^0.6.12",
        "angular2-in-memory-web-api": "0.0.9",
        "bootstrap": "^3.3.6"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "typescript": "^1.8.11"
    }
}
```

What would cause these sorts of errors?

UPDATE: I am able to get the TS compiled and running using gulp and npm tsc with no problems, it's just the VS2013 compile that fails.

Comment: I'm having the same exact problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'm glad that I can help you.

I had same problem today and I solved it.

my TS compiled well at npm tsc, but not vs2013 only,

you need to put this at project src,

```
<TypeScriptCompileBlocked>true</TypeScriptCompileBlocked>
```

:)